# Logic problem, it is possible? Add more quotelineitems if it has more than 1 on quantity

Tags: query, list, loop, quotelineitem, for

- Hello Guys.
- My method does not work correctly.
- What it does is call another method inside a loop, the functionality
  is to take each quotelineitem from the quote until it finishes
  collecting all the quotelineitems there are. (The method takes one
  quotelineitem at a time, that's why the loop).
- My problem arises when I want to add an extra quotelineitem if its
  quantity is greater than one, also concatenating a number
  1-2-3-...-etc , depending on the quantity in the quoteline item.
- My first code works fine, skipping the quantity part inside the
  quotelineitem The second code is when I try to add an extra
  quotelineitem depending on the amount, which is where I need your
  help guys.
- The problem specific is the first code

  Thank you, good day :)

**First Code**

```
public static String SendEpics(String oppId, String idproject){
        Quote quotes = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId =: oppId AND IsSyncing=true LIMIT 1];    
        List<QuoteLineItem> qlitems = [SELECT Id, Product2.Name, Product2.Description, Quantity FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId =: quotes.Id];
        //Example in the quoteline items list
        //ProductA, ProductB, ProductC
        //On product C, on quantity field I have 3, so I need to extend the quotelineitems like:
        //ProductA, ProductB, ProductC1, ProductC2, ProductC3
        for(Quotelineitem qli :qlitems){
            //What is doing?
            //Executing the method by passing it one quotelineitem per loop until all quotelineitems are finished
            postEpicIssuesIndividual(oppId, idproject, qli); //Here is calling one method that need one quotelineitem per call, I cant do it with a list
            
            //What should do now?
            //More quotelineitems should be added if the number in them is greater than 1.
            //Example: If the quantity of one of the quotelineitems is 2, 
            //I have to add 2 quotelineitems instead of 1, concatenating a number. example; quotelineItemExample1, quotelineItemExample2
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**This is what im trying**

```
public static String SendEpics(String oppId, String idproject){
        Quote quotes = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId =: oppId AND IsSyncing=true LIMIT 1];    
        List<QuoteLineItem> qlitems = [SELECT Id, Product2.Name, Product2.Description, Quantity FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId =: quotes.Id];
        
        for(Quotelineitem qli :qlitems){
            if(qli.Quantity > 1){
                for(Integer i = 0; i > qli.Quantity; i++){                
                    qli.Product2.Name = qli.Product2.Name + i;
                    qli.Product2.Description = qli.Product2.Description;
                    qlitems.add(qli);
                }   
            }
            postEpicIssuesIndividual(oppId, idproject, qli);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Final Code, skip the items is missing**

```
public static String SendEpics(String oppId, String idproject){
        Quote quotes = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId =: oppId AND IsSyncing=true LIMIT 1];
        List<QuoteLineItem> qlitems = [SELECT Id, Product2.Name, Product2.Description, Quantity FROM QuoteLineItem WHERE QuoteId =: quotes.Id];
        
        Quotelineitem[] extraLineItems = new Quotelineitem[]{};
        for(Integer i = 0; i < qlitems.size(); i++){
            Quotelineitem qli = qlitems[i];
            if(qli.Quantity > 1){
                for(Integer j = 1; j <= qli.Quantity; j++){   
                    Quotelineitem newQli = qli.clone(false,true,false,false);             
                    newQli.Product2.Name = qli.Product2.Name + ' ' + j;
                    newQli.Product2.Description = qli.Product2.Description;
                    extraLineItems.add(newQli);
                }   
            }            
            postEpicIssuesIndividual(oppId, idproject, qli);
            System.debug('All Qli: ' + qli);
            
        }
        //do the extra ones
        for(Quotelineitem qli :extraLineItems){
            
            postEpicIssuesIndividual(oppId, idproject, qli);
            System.debug('Qli Extra: ' + qli);
            
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few issues with this code:

- You are appending to the loop while looping through it. This will cause a run-time error.
- You have your `for` loop setup wrongly - it won't iterate at all like this.

Here's my version with that stuff fixed:

**EDIT**
Made two iterators - we need to keep track of the original QuoteLineItem and also the extra items being added. See the part when I'm using them both to make a unique identifier - `Name + i + '' + j;`

**NOTE**  You will not be able to save these items to the database, as you are attempting to change the name of a Product through a relationship, which is not allowed.

However, it might be ok if you are just using this for a callout.

```
Quotelineitem[] extraLineItems = new Quotelineitem[]{};
for(Integer i = 0; i < qlitems; i++){
   Quotelineitem qli = qlitems[i];   
    if(qli.Quantity > 1){
        for(Integer j = 0; j < qli.Quantity; j++){   
            Quotelineitem newQli = qli.clone(false,true,false,false);              
            newQli.Product2.Name = qli.Product2.Name + i + '' + j;
            newQli.Product2.Description = qli.Product2.Description;
            extraLineItems.add(newQli);
        }   
    }
    postEpicIssuesIndividual(oppId, idproject, qli);
}
//do the extra ones
for(Quotelineitem qli :extraLineItems){
    postEpicIssuesIndividual(oppId, idproject, qli);
}
return null;
```

To skip the first item, do something like this:

`for(Integer i = 1; i < qli.Quantity; i++){`

You should be wary of this code - if you are doing something in the method that modifies data (and it looks like you are)... you pretty much have DML in a for loop (or a callout in a `for` loop).

Both of these are bad and you should think of a way to avoid.

Comment: Thanks bro, I got you, it works :) . But this is an array, so it is storing the same info haha. I mean, it's okay but I want to add some characters to the name, thats why I was adding the 'i' to the item. Something like, qli1, qli2, or something like to identify each element.

Comment: The result was like
qli12, qli12

Comment: Hi again bro. It is working hehe, it was a error in this part : for(Integer i = 0; i < qlitems; i++). So my code is updated here in the post. My problem is to skip the first quotelineitems that have more than 1 in quantity. If I replace my for with your for, it is skipping the first qlitem, I mean, the first quotelineitem in the list

Comment: Yes getting that right is key :)

Comment: The last code hah